# How to increase count value when we checked the checkboxes in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

When I checked checkboxes one by one ,the count value should be increased and the same value should be showed in place of paragraph tag and same case should be happened while I unchecked too.

The above intend behavior is not happening.

Could any one please guide me to resolve this issue.

**HTML file and controller.js**

```
<html ng-app="controllers">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>{{"Contact " + "list"}}</h2>
        <p id="demo" align="center"></p>

        <div ng-controller='userCtrl'>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>Status</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Number</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in contacts">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="name1" onchange="getElementById('demo').innerHTML=contactCount()"></td>
                    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.number}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
                var count = 0;
                function contactCount()
                {
                    var y=document.getElemenetById("name1").checked;
                    if(Number(y)== 1)
                    {
                    count+=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    count;
                    }
                    return count;
                }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>


**controller.js**

var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
controllers.controller('userCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.contacts=[
                  {name:"Mr X",number:"1234"},
                  {name:"Mr Y",number:"4567"},
                  {name:"Mrs Z",number:"0214"},
                  {name:"Mr A",number:"9564"}
                     ];
});
```

Comment: Why not simply display the number of checked checkboxes? (i.e. `someElement.textContent = document.querySelectorAll("input[name='name1']:checked").length;`)

Comment: there is mistype error in your code document.getElemenetById("name1") should be document.getElementById("name1")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a spelling mistake in your code.

```
var y=document.getElemenetById("name1").checked;
```

should be like this

```
var y=document.getElementById("name1").checked;
```

you typed `getElemenetById` and it should be `getElementById`

```js
var controllers = angular.module('controllers', []);
controllers.controller('userCtrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.contacts=[
                  {name:"Mr X",number:"1234"},
                  {name:"Mr Y",number:"4567"},
                  {name:"Mrs Z",number:"0214"},
                  {name:"Mr A",number:"9564"}
                     ];
});
```

```html
<html ng-app="controllers">
    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="controllers.js"></script>

    </head>

    <body>
        <h2>{{"Contact " + "list"}}</h2>
        <p id="demo" align="center"></p>

        <div ng-controller='userCtrl'>
            <table align="center">
                <tr>
                    <td>Status</td>
                    <td>Name</td>
                    <td>Number</td>
                </tr>
                <tr ng-repeat="x in contacts">
                    <td><input type="checkbox" id="name1" onchange="getElementById('demo').innerHTML=contactCount()"></td>
                    <td>{{x.name}}</td>
                    <td>{{x.number}}</td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
        <script>
                var count = 0;
                function contactCount()
                {
                    var y= document.getElementById("name1").checked;
                    if(Number(y)== 1)
                    {
                    count+=1;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    count;
                    }
                    return count;
                }
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```